Inquiry About the Nyström Method and Matrix Inversion
I have been studying the Nyström method for obtaining low-rank approximations of matrices and would like to inquire about its applicability in calculating the inverse of a matrix.
In my research, I came across the following article: Nyström approximation. However, I am unclear about how the authors applied the Woodbury identity to compute the inverse in this context.
I understood up to equation (1)
\begin{align} K = K_{22} &= K_{21} U_1 \underbrace{\Lambda^{-1} \Lambda}_{I} \Lambda^{-1} U_1^\top K_{12} \\ &= K_{21} U_1 \Lambda^{-1} U_1^\top K_{12}. \tag{1} \label{eq:K22} \end{align}
After that, I am not able to follow: how to calculate $K^{-1}$ using Woodbury identity.
\begin{align}
K^{-1} = K_{22}^{-1} = K_{21} U_1 \underbrace{(\Lambda + U_1^\top K_{12} K_{21} U_1)^{-1}}_{m \times m} U_1^\top K_{12}.
\end{align}
Could someone please assist me in understanding this aspect?
Additionally, I would appreciate any insights into alternative approaches for calculating the matrix inverse using the Nyström approximation.
Thank you for your assistance.

This question is cross-posted to Signal Processing, as well. I will, for the sake of completeness, include my response here, too:
I would use it as follows. First, assume that $K\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$ is of rank $r$ where $r<<p$. Let's pick $B=\Lambda^{-1}$, $C=K_{21}U_1$ to write:
$$
(\epsilon I + K_{21}U_1\Lambda^{-1}U_1^\top K_{12})^{-1} = (\epsilon I + CBC^\top)^{-1},
$$
where $\epsilon$ is a very small constant, e.g. added for stability. As $\epsilon\to 0$ this quantity approaches $K^{-1}$, yet requires inverting an $p\times p$ matrix. At this point we invoke the Woodbury identity:
$$
\begin{align}
(A + CBC^\top)^{-1}&={A}^{-1}-{A}^{-1} {C}\left({B}^{-1}+{C}^{\top} {A}^{-1} {C}\right)^{-1} {C}^{\top} {A}^{-1}\\
&=\frac1{\epsilon}I-\frac1{\epsilon^2} C\left(B^{-1}+\frac1{\epsilon}C^{\top} C\right)^{-1} C^{\top}\\
&=\frac1{\epsilon}I-\frac1{\epsilon^2} K_{21}U_1\left(\Lambda+\frac1{\epsilon}U_1^{\top}K_{12} K_{21}U_1\right)^{-1} U_1^\top K_{12},
\end{align}
$$
where $A=\epsilon I_p$ and we frequently used $K_{12} =K_{21}^\top$ (and vice versa) to eliminate the transpositions. Notice that the only inversion required in the last equation is of size $r\times r$. This seems to correspond to some parts of the identity that you mentioned but I'm not sure if they are the same up to some approximation. Essentially what I have here is $(\epsilon I+K)^{-1}$ and only for some small $\epsilon$, it recovers $K^{-1}$.
This trick can be understood from the perspective of regularized Hessians, but I will not delve into the details here. Some further information can be found at Singh et al. [*].
[*] Singh, Dinesh, Hardik Tankaria, and Makoto Yamada. "Nys-newton: Nystr" om-approximated curvature for stochastic optimization." arXiv preprint (2021). https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.08577.
